# Why must const class members be static to be properly optimised?

Tags: c++, optimization, constants

Given:

```
class Foo {        const int x = 5; public: inline int get() { return x; } };
class Bar { static const int x = 5; public: inline int get() { return x; } };
int fn0(Foo& f) { return f.get(); }
int fn1(Bar& b) { return b.get(); }
```

Compiled output gives a memory fetch to read the value of `x` in `fn0()`, whereas adding `static` results the literal `5` being inlined in `fn1()`.  The implication is that a caller to `get()` can be optimised as if it were using a constant in place of `get()` only when the integer constant is static.

I have more complex situations where `static` is not appropriate.  Derived classes initialise `x` to different values through the constructor; but to each of those classes `x` is a constant and those class methods could be optimised, as with the preceeding `static` case, if only `get()` evaluated to a true constant.

In fact, my commonest case is with the initialisation of references in the base class:

```
class Foo { int& x; public: Foo(int& init) : x(init) {} inline int get() { return x; } };
class Bar : public Foo { int m; public: Bar() : Foo(m) {} inline int getget() { return get(); };
int fn1(Bar& b) { return b.getget(); }
```

Here, if `get()` evaluated directly to `Bar::m` within `getget()` I would avoid a level of pointer indirection.  This will not be possible if `x` is static.

It's not clear to me why `static` is necessary to allow this optimisation.

Comment: So there was, briefly, an answer pointing out that `static` members can be placed in a read-only segment so their const property is enforced by hardware.  Even if it's not an answer according to the spec, I do think it's noteworthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `static const int` member initialized in-class is a true constant expression, that is, a compile-time constant.

A non-static `const int` member cannot be changed after it is initialized, but it is harder for the compiler to determine statically that it can only have one possible value. Note that a *brace-or-equal-initializer* for a non-static data member is only used if there is no *mem-initializer* for that member. This means that if for example you had this:

```
class Foo {
    const int x = 5;
  public:
    inline int get() { return x; }
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int x) : x(x) {}
};
```

then `Foo::x` could be `5`, if the default constructor is called, or it could be something else, if `Foo::Foo(int)` is called. Also consider what happens if the member is made public:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    const int x = 5;
    inline int get() { return x; }
};
```

Now it's possible to use aggregate initialization:

```
Foo f {42};
// f.x is 42
```

In the particular case of the `Foo` that you wrote, I believe it is true that `Foo::x` can only ever be `5`, but it isn't as easy for the compiler to determine this as it would be if `Foo::x` were a static data member. Quite possibly the compiler implementers simply didn't bother to write such an optimization.